# Getting a Login Timeout Expired: A network related or instance specific... While trying to export data from one server to another

Tags: sql-server, database, database-administration

I am trying to export data from a table in a server to another server that has the same table. The table contains about 500 Million records, Generating a script requires memory that our server doesnt seem to have since it gives us an error midway. I was trying to use the export data wizard tool. I chose native client 11.0 as the source and specified the server. But when i specify the the destination server it gives me an error.

Login timeout expired: A network related or instance specific error has occured while establishing a connection to the server. Server is not found or accessible...

I am also worried I might have to deal with duplicate data if I use this tool.

Is there a way I can copy/backup/restore a specific table in SQL server and simply restore it on the other server?

I am looking for the most efficient solution to this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The title and the question appear to be completely unrelated here. *"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server."* has nothing to do with migrating data from one instance to another.

Comment: I get this error as soon as i put in the server name in the destination section of the export data wizard on sql server. I am using the SQL server import export wizard

Comment: So is your question about the error, or how to copy the data across..? If the former, then this is a dupe of [Why am I getting “Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)